# Meaning of "paddling hell-for-leather away from a harmless seal"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm reading [The Inflatable Volunteer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006NU15NW) by Steve Aylett, and I'm stuck with this sentence:

> Last week I was flooding the banks with saliva, slivers of gill and drifting snot, paddling hell-for-leather away from a harmless seal.

It's a pretty bizarre novel, so I don't know if I don't understand because of my bad English or if this was the author intention.

Comment: I don't like to seem harsh, but the *meaning* of this expression really is "general reference". Even without any "cue" words like *"definition"* or *"meaning"*, if I Google *"hell-for-leather"*, there's a clear definition in the second result. If you'd asked about the **origin**, it might be a different story (but actually, it looks like there's no certainty on that front).

Comment: I looked for hell-for-leather before ask here. Sorry anyway.

Comment: Even knowing what all the terms mean doesn't help me understand this sentence. How do saliva, snot, and a harmless seal combine into a single coherent idea?

Comment: @Martha: Steve Aylett has a reputation for bizarre writing style. To quote [one reviewer here](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1183563.The_Inflatable_Volunteer) - *"like a stream of made-up idioms being hurled fervently from character to character- much like the 3-stooges on crack, standing on a street corner, pestering you with their nonsense while you wait for the bus to hell."*. OP has made a singularly bad choice if he's reading this in order to improve his grasp of English!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Isn’t the normal phrase “hell-bent for leather”?

Comment: @tchrist: I'm familiar with [hell-bent](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=MvIaAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA179&dq=%22hell-bent+on+carnage%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yhRRT57bCarS0QXTt4zmCw&ved=0CEgQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22hell-bent%20on%20carnage%22&f=false) = *"exceptionally determined"*, and *"hell for leather"* = *"at breakneck speed"*. The first seems to have been around since at least 1824; the second seems much later. I don't recognise that combination of the two, I think that's even later, but I don't really know.

Comment: ...[hell for leather](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22hell+for+leather%22&hl=en&biw=1264&bih=902&sa=X&ei=DBZRT_ffNumw0QX12IHtCw&ved=0CBwQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1700%2Ccd_max%3A31%2F12%2F1875&tbm=bks) from 1843. Earliest *hell-bent for leather* I can find is 1878.

Comment: A good candidate for literatureSE / writersSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that he's paddling at great speed away from a harmless seal. (not sure if in your passage this is literally a "harmless seal" or he just means something else which is equally non-threatening)

Answer (score 1):

paddling = propelling oneself (usually using a paddle, but not necessarily)

hell-for-leather = as fast as possible

harmless = lacking the capacity or intent to injure

seal = aquatic mammal